# Loop through array of objects, if value exists, return another value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

With the information below I am trying loop through `cards`, if there is a nested object of `helper`, return that objects `title`. But am either receiving undefined or errors. I was thinking maybe reduce would be viable here?

Sample Array:

```
cards: [
    0: {
        title: 'Something',
        logo: 'logo link here',
    },
    1: {
        title: 'Something 2',
        logo: 'logo link here',
        helper: {
            text: 'helper text',
        },
    },
    2: {
        title: 'Something 3',
        logo: 'logo link here',
    },
]
```

code:

```
cards.filter((item) => {
    if (item.helper) setHelperActive({...helperActive, item.title: true}) 
})
```

Comment: `cards` does not appear to be a valid array to me. Also: `setHelperActive` being invoked from within the `.filter()` is also not very typical (at least from what I've seen). A `.filter()` is expected to return truthy (to keep/filter-in) or falsy (to discard/filter-out) for every element of the array. In this case, the `cards.filter()` does not return anything.

Comment: Hard to tell exactly what you're trying to achieve here. Whatever it is though, I don't believe that .filter() is the array method you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `.filter()` and checking if the object has a prop named `helper`. In case of multiple objects matching the criteria, their title's will be joined as a comma-separated string.

**Snippet**

```js
let cards = [
    {
        title: 'Something',
        logo: 'logo link here',
    },
    {
        title: 'Something 2',
        logo: 'logo link here',
        helper: {
            text: 'helper text',
        },
    },
    {   
        title: 'Something',
        logo: 'logo link here',
    },
    {
        title: 'Something 4',
        logo: 'logo link here',
        helper: {
            text: 'helper text',
        },
    },
]

// to list titles from all matching objects as a comma-separated string
console.log(cards.filter(ob => 'helper' in ob).map(({ title }) => title).join());

// suppose only the first matched object's title is required
console.log(cards.find(ob => 'helper' in ob)?.title ?? 'no match found');
```

Comment: This is exactly what i was trying to do, thanks so much!

Comment: yw. In case only the first-matched object's title is needed, it's even simpler to do using `.find()`. Have added that on the answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let cards = [
    {
        title: 'Something',
        logo: 'logo link here',
    },
    {
        title: 'Something else',
        logo: 'logo link here',
        helper: {
            text: 'helper text',
        },
    },
    {   
        title: 'Something',
        logo: 'logo link here',
    },
    {
        title: 'Lorem Epsum',
        logo: 'logo link here',
        helper: {
            text: 'helper text',
        },
    }
]

let filtered = []

for(let i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
    if(cards[i].helper) {
        filtered.push(cards[i].title)
    }
}
console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: The fact that all 3 elements have the same `title` makes it difficult to evaluate whether it's the first, or second or last element's title being console-logged. Wondering if something like this: `console.log(cards.filter(ob => 'helper' in ob).map(({ title }) => title).join());` would suffice in this case (still won't tell us which element's title is logged, though :-)).

Comment: That's just for example and I apologize for that, I've edited the original post. there shouldn't be a scenario where the title is the same. Sorry about that.

Comment: I've changed the title where helper is defined. the data he's trying to loop through is neither JSON nor array. I changed it to array.

Answer (score 0):

the solution  is to use map not filter should be  like this:
`var titles =  cards.map(card=>{ return card.title })`

Comment: When i use map, it returns  undefined where item.helper is not true and imo that doesnt seem like the best case scenario when my state is [undefined, undefined, title, undefined, undefined]. Which is why i only want it returned if true, not undefined.